# Wordpress displaying user registration date as 1970

Tags: php, wordpress

I can't figure out where WordPress is grabbing the registration date for one of the bloggers on their site - http://www.redbarninc.com/author/redbarnpp/

What's weird is that it displays the correct date (March 2012) when I'm logged in as as admin.

Here's the code I'm adding to the author.php file to display the registration date:

```
<p class="blogger-since">Blogger Since <?php echo date("M Y", strtotime(get_userdata(get_current_user_id( ))->user_registered)); ?></p>
```

Thank You

Answer (score 1):

`get_current_user_id()` checks the ID of the user currently viewing the page (`0` for logged out users, hence no registration date). Instead, check the author meta for the author queried as follows:

```
<?php
    global $wp_query;
    $registered = date_i18n( "M Y", strtotime( get_the_author_meta( 'user_registered', $wp_query->queried_object_id ) ) );
?>
<p class="blogger-since">Blogger Since <?php echo $registered; ?></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Date values are stored as a number representing the time in seconds since 1 January 1970 (called the Epoch).

A value of 0 will translate to 1 January 1970 00:00:00;
A value of 1 will translate to 1 January 1970 00:00:01;
...and so on...

The function date_i18n() the way you used it transform the time to a human readable format.

```
date_i18n("M Y", $some_value)
```

Therefore, You must examine the value you are passing to the function.